# highchart bar data, borders fit to the data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've searched a lot on SO & Highcarts documentation but couldn't find anything.

I have a **bar chart** with negative and positive values and since i'll be using a wide daterange, **i need to avoid** as many **blank space** as i can. I would like the chart to **fit to the borders** (bottom and top of the chart), to use all the height available.

Here is the jdfiddle of what i've tried so far : http://jsfiddle.net/816kh4ev/

```
yAxis: {
    //floor: -200,
    //min: -200
    //maxPadding: 0.01,
    endOnTick: false        
 },
```

"EndOnTick" options is kinda great, but i want **the negative value** to **stick to the bottom too**.

I'm out of ideas (min, floor, endOnTick, maxpadding), so if one of you is an highchart master, it would be amazing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you have [`endOnTick`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick), you have [`startOnTick`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.startOnTick) which is the same, but for the minimum value.

```
yAxis: {
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false        
},
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/816kh4ev/7.

In addition to that, you can reduce padding:

```
yAxis: {
  minPadding: 0.01,
  maxPadding: 0.01,
  startOnTick: false,
  endOnTick: false        
},
```

Note that [`minPadding`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.minPadding)/[`maxPadding`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.maxPadding) means padding for the min value and padding for the max value.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/816kh4ev/10/.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's so obvious i can't believe i missed it.